# if statement to only show data that has ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple view that returns all the results from the database, however for the id sometimes there is data and sometimes there is not.

I need a way, maybe a if statement to show the results that only have id.

Any ideas how I will do this with a view like this:

```
    <table id="ListGrid" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.number)
        </th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (M1DAL.test.Stion intem in Model.AllSlised)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.number)
            </td>
              <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a filter

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(m => m.Id != null))
```